# beforeinstallprompt event is triggered for a origin or for a service worker scope

Tags: google-chrome, web, firefox, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

Assume we have a website `www.example.com` and we are running 2 different service worker under different scopes.

- `www.example.com/pwa1` (scope `/pwa1`)
- `www.example.com/pwa2` (scope `/pwa2`)

Now we want to allow users to install these PWA as an app in their launcher. And browser trigger `beforeinstallprompt` event to handle this, based on a few [criteria](https://web.dev/install-criteria/#criteria). Also, if the user declines the installation, it might not trigger this event for the next 3 months.

So my questions are:

1. Do we get `beforeinstallprompt` event triggered separately for `pwa1` and `pwa2` or is it considered for an origin?
2. If the user declines the prompt in `pwa1`, does this have any impact in `pwa2`?

Comment: Ref: https://web.dev/multi-origin-pwas/#installation

Answer (score 1):

1. The `beforeinstallprompt` event will be triggered separately. A PWA is based on the manifest and the scope defined in it.
2. Chrome treats them as separate apps, if the user accepts or declines one, it will not affect the other.

> Also, if the user declines the installation, it might not trigger this event for the next 3 months.

This is **only** the case for the mini-infobar shown on Chrome for Android. The `beforeinstallprompt` event will always be triggered if the site meets the [install criteria](https://web.dev/install-criteria/), allowing you to add your own [install promotion](https://web.dev/customize-install/).

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. I'll confirm and accept it.